# Text does not set to div's width

Tags: html, css

I have a very normal div and inside I have some text. the div is styles with `test-align:center;`and have a fixed width of 360px. The problem is when I try and enter some text without any spaces between words, the whole document would not break and commit to the div's width, it would just get out of the div's width I set it. 
I know that in a real life situation no one would write a document without any spaces between words, but I just want to achieve this.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">SomeDummyTextWithNoSpaceInBetwenn</div>
```

CSS

```
width:350px;
display: block;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
```

Comment: paste your code please

Comment: might be a typo in your question, css should be "text-align" not "test-align"

Comment: Nah, I made that mistake while just writing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style the way text wraps inside a div with CSS using `word-wrap:breakword`

```css
div{ width:360px; background:#555; color:#eee }
#withWordWrap{ word-wrap:break-word }
```

```html
<div id="withoutWordWrap">
  ThisIsSomeTextWithoutAnySpacesAtallInsideThisDivThisIsSomeTextWithoutAnySpacesAtallInsideThisDiv
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="withWordWrap">
  ThisIsSomeTextWithoutAnySpacesAtallInsideThisDivThisIsSomeTextWithoutAnySpacesAtallInsideThisDiv
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `word-wrap: break-word;`